# Pass a whole struct in c through a pipe

Tags: c, struct, pipe

I need to pass this struct through a pipe:

```
typedef struct Student {
  char * name;
  char * average;
} Student;

typedef struct Connection {
  int fd;
  int dataSize;
  void * data;
} Connection;

typedef struct Request {    
  int action;
  Connection * connection;
} Request;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write the Student struct and how to read it. I can read correctly the fd, action and dataSize, but I could't fix it for the structure. I Hope you can help me. Perhaps there is an easier way to do this and pass the whole entire request structure.

So I did this on the client side:
(writeNamedPipe uses write)

```
requestState writeRequest(Request * request, int fd) {
  writeNamedPipe(fd, &request -> action, sizeof(int));
  writeNamedPipe(fd, &request -> connection -> fd, sizeof(int));
  writeNamedPipe(fd, &request -> connection -> dataSize, sizeof(int));
  writeNamedPipe(fd, &request -> connection -> data, request -> connection -> dataSize);
  return REQUEST_OK;
}
```

And this in the server side:

```
Request * getRequest(Connection * connection) {
  Request *request; 
  int action, fd = 0;
  int dataSize;
  void * data;
  read(connection-> fd, &action, sizeof(int));
  read(connection-> fd, &fd, sizeof(int));
  read(connection-> fd, &dataSize, sizeof(int));
  data = malloc (dataSize);
  read(connection-> fd, data, dataSize);
  request = createRequest(action, fd, dataSize, data);
  return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Student struct only contain pointers, so you cannot send the whole struct at once. It would be possible if you had fix array instead of dynamically allocated ones.

example:

```
struct Student {
    char name[32];
    char average[16];
};
```

I guess this would probably answers your question:

[C - serialization techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002528/c-serialization-techniques)