# Write - Read structure in binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I'm just trying to write a Point structure in binary file and to read the written structure.

Can someone explain me why this code is not working ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 100

typedef struct Point Point;
struct Point{
    float x;
    float y;
};

void initialisePoint(Point * p);
void showPoint(Point * p);
void initialiseFileName(char * fileName);
int writePointToFile(char * fileName, Point * p);
int readPointFromFile(char * fileName, Point * p);

int main()
{
    Point p1 = {0};
    Point p2 = {0};
    char fileName[N] = {0};
    int exitStatus = 0;

    initialisePoint(&p1);
    showPoint(&p1);

    initialiseFileName(fileName);

    printf("Vous avez entré : %s\n", fileName);

    printf("Write return : %d\n", writePointToFile(fileName, &p1));

    printf("Read return : %d\n", readPointFromFile(fileName, &p2));

    showPoint(&p2);

    return exitStatus;
}

void initialisePoint(Point * p){
    printf("Entrez une valeur pour x : ");
    scanf("%f", &p->x);
    printf("Entrez une valeur pour y : ");
    scanf("%f", &p->y);
}
void showPoint(Point * p){
    printf("Le point est aux coordonnées (x,y) = (%.2lf, %.2lf).\n", p->x, p->y);
}
void initialiseFileName(char * fileName){
    printf("Entrez une valeur pour le nom de fichier : ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
}
int writePointToFile(char * fileName, Point * p)
{
    FILE* f2 = NULL;

    f2 = fopen(fileName, "wb");

    if(f2 != NULL){
        if(fwrite(&p, sizeof(struct Point), 1, f2) != 1){
            printf("Could not write to file.");
            fclose(f2);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not open file.");
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
int readPointFromFile(char * fileName, Point * p){

    FILE* f = NULL;

    f = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    if(f != NULL){
        if(fread(&p, sizeof(struct Point), 1, f) != 1){
            printf("Could not read from file.");
            fclose(f);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Could not open file.");
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

There is my log :

> /home/sviktor/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/untitled Entrez
>   une valeur pour x : 2.33 Entrez une valeur pour y : 1.34 Le point est
>   aux coordonnées (x,y) = (2.33, 1.34). Entrez une valeur pour le nom de
>   fichier : test123.bin Vous avez entré : test123.bin Write return : 0
>   Read return : 0 Le point est aux coordonnées (x,y) = (0.00, 0.00).
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I'm working on Fedora and clion IDE,

Bless editor says that my test123.bin file contains this `C4 2E 18 F1 FC 7F 00 00` but the read function is not working (it's giving point = (0,0))

Comment: What do you see if you check your output file with a hexeditor? Was it written correctly?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: When calling `fread` and `fwrite`, try passing `p` instead of `&p` as the first parameter. `p` is the address of the structure; `&p` is the address of the pointer variable holding the address of the structure. The latter is a bit too much, I suppose.

Comment: `fread(&p, sizeof(struct Point)` ==> `fread(p, sizeof(struct Point)` - note the first parameter.

Comment: There is more wrong to it than just this though. Generally, you should **not** write structures to a file like this. There is no guarantee on the actual layout of the structure, so it's very possible that recompiling your program on another compiler, or a later version of same compiler, or the exact same compiler with different options will make your program incompatible with the files you saved. You should implement [proper serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002528/c-serialization-techniques) instead, writing values in a controlled way.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm a litle surprised that the IDE did not given any warning for this... Specially thank to @spectras to show me how to go deeper with this !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `writePointToFile()` and `readPointFromFile()` functions accept a pointer to your `Point` structure, you want to pass that pointer to `fread` and `fwrite`.  It's a pointer your data, which is what you want to read and write.  Your code is incorrectly passing a pointer to that pointer.

In other words, in `writePointToFile()`, you want to change the call

```
fwrite(&p, sizeof(struct Point), 1, f2)
```

to

```
fwrite(p, sizeof(struct Point), 1, f2)
```

and similarly for the `fread` call in `readPointFromFile()`.