# Reading a binary file into structure variable giving seg fault

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I have a below sample file where I read the binary into structure and print the length of the string which is stored in structure. But I get a segmentation fault core dumped when I try to print the full string. I could not find the reason for it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sample {
        unsigned int m;
        unsigned int v;
        unsigned int s[128];
        int t_length;
        char *t;
};

int main()
{
        int i=0;
        unsigned int t_len=0;
        FILE *fp;
        struct sample sam;
        fp =fopen("sample.bin", "rb");
        if (fp==NULL) {
                printf("File not created\n");
                return -1;
        }
        fread(&sam, sizeof(sam), 1, fp);
        printf("t_length is %d\n", sam.t_length);
        t_len=sam.t_length;
        sam.t=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * t_len);
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
        fread(&sam, sizeof(sam)+t_len, 1, fp);
        printf("t_length is %d\n", t_len);
        printf("%s\n", sam.t);
        fclose(fp);
        free(sam.t);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: You also present the program that created the binary file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sorry I cannot give it

Comment: Why have you added the C++ tag? Are you programming in C or in C++? They are two very different languages, so please edit your question to remove the language tag that's not relevant (probably the C++ tag, since your program is a pure C program).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK

Comment: Sidenote: Abusing structs for serialization is generally considered bad practice, because of limited control on things like endianness or padding. It would be better to serialize each member separately.

Comment: @user694733 Could you please explain more about serialization as I am unaware of it

Comment: compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`) to run  your program step by step and watch relevant variables. Check result of `fread`

Comment: @arceus You can start by reading [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6002528/694733).There are plenty of information on this on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following lines:

```
    fread(&sam, sizeof(sam), 1, fp);
    // ...
    sam.t=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * t_len);
    // ...
    fread(&sam, sizeof(sam)+t_len, 1, fp);
```

You read the structure. You assign the `t` member. Then you read the structure again, ***overwriting*** the `t` member.

This will lead to the `t` member no longer pointing to the memory you allocated, and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you dereference the pointer.

I suggest you do some research about [*flexible array members*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) as that might solve your problem. This of course requires that the program *writing* the file also be changed to use a flexible array member.

If you can't modify the program writing the file, then don't re-read the structure. Read the structure once, allocate memory, then read *only* the data to be put in the memory you allocated. Skip the seek, as the file should be at the correct position anyway.

---

In code something like

```
fread(&sam, sizeof sam , 1, fp);
sam.t = malloc(samr.t_length);
fread(sam.t, sam.t_length, 1, fp);
```

Comment: I could not understand. Could you please explain more with a sample program.

Comment: @arceus What you're doing is roughly equivalent to `int a; a = 10; a = 5;` and then wonder why `a` is not equal to `10`. If you step through the code, line by line, in a debugger you can see the value of the pointer change.

Comment: OK. But I removed the first fread and I am still facing "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @arceus Then you don't read the `t_length` member. Keep the first, remove the second, remove the seek, then read the data into `sam.t` instead.

Comment: @arceus Yes. The first `fread` read the structure, *and* positions the file-pointer at the correct place to read the string. Then you allocate the memory. Then you read (without any seeking) the data to be placed in the allocated memory.

Comment: I did that. Now there is no seg fault but full data is not printed. i.e., string (sam.t) is not printed.

Comment: @arceus Then you need to see how the data was written to the file. ***And*** add error checking for the `fread` calls. It is a different problem though, that should warrant a separate question if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: Ya now after I followed ur edited code, I am getting " Second t_length as 0" and some characters from beginning of string is getting truncated. Rest all is fine. I want second t_length to be same as first.

Comment: @arceus Again, you ***need to know how the file was written***. You need to know its format. Perhaps the pointer of the structure isn't written? Perhaps the writer used flexible array members? And since my code doesn't set `t_len`, you changed to print `sam.t_length` the second time as well? And it's *still* a subject for another question.